# Add 0 to empty csv cells using Groovy

Tags: csv, groovy, ant

Im using a groovy script to concatenate between 2 fields on a CSV files.
The script is working perfectly except it collapse once it hits empty cells.

I managed to use a powershell script to avoid this thing but then i got stuck with encoding issue

```
    <groovy>
  ant.mkdir(dir:"target")


  new File("target/UpsertCheckDeals.csv").withWriter {
    new File("C:/Users/alon\Documents\CheckDealBeforeUpsert.csv").splitEachLine(",") { Customer__c, Name__c, Deal__c, Amount__c, CheckCount__c, Discount__c ->
       it.println "${Customer__c},${Name__c},${CheckCount__c},${Deal__c},${Amount__c},${Discount__c},${Customer__c}-${Deal__c }"
    }
  }

</groovy>
```

Any suggestions how to solve this with groovy?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's supposed to happen upon encountering empty cells?

Comment: Its throwing error messages

Comment: Please be more specific. A self-contained --so anyone can run it-- example that reproduces the problem would be even better.

Comment: See related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407444/quotes-appearing-on-csv-after-concatnate-fields-using-groovy/41417408#41417408 Using openCSV enables a check on the number of fields in the row

Answer (score 0):

Without details on the error, I'm going to assume the `splitEachLine` method cannot split the line into enough parts in order to assign values to all of the Closure's declared arguments.

To workaround this, I would use a single-arg closure. The single argument is assigned an array (List?) of the split values. You can check the length of the array before you attempt to process the row.

```
new File("target/UpsertCheckDeals.csv").withWriter {
    new File("C:/Users/alon\Documents\CheckDealBeforeUpsert.csv").splitEachLine(",") { parts ->
        if (parts.length != 6) return // or maybe it's .size()
        (Customer__c, Name__c, Deal__c, Amount__c, CheckCount__c, Discount__c) = parts
        it.println "${Customer__c},${Name__c},${CheckCount__c},${Deal__c},${Amount__c},${Discount__c},${Customer__c}-${Deal__c }"
    }
  }
```